# SearchView behavior If It must support OS before HoneyComb

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-2.3-gingerbread, searchview

I found out that there is a way to support devices with older OS (GingerBread and Older) even if you are using SearchView function that is designed for HoneyComb and Later OS. I tried putting this method as it was show in the docs:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.search:
            onSearchRequested();
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

Now, when I first click the Search button at the action bar

- the actionbar turns white
- I press the back arrow beside the icon, actionbar turns black, but search box is still not closed.
- I type something, press Enter then Search Activity is shown.
- I click the search button again, the Action bar background turns to black again.

Can you explain why is this happening? I am running the app on Galaxy S4. Thanks for those who will respond.

Comment: Your galaxy s4 runs gingerbread?

Comment: haha no. I'm just saying that I am running it on a jellybean OS, so I don't know what will be the behavior if I run it on gingerbread.

Comment: Also I have the method `OnCreateOptionsMenu`, I'm just trying to find out why this is happening.